# Automatic lens aggregation

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I've just discover `makeClass` from the `lens` package. It allows you to things like

```
data Point2 = Point2 { _x:: Double, _y :: Double }
makeClassy ''Point2

data Point3 = Point3 { _p2 : Point2, _z :: Double}
makeclassy ''Point3

instance HasPoint2 Point3 where
    point2 = p2
```

You can then do things like

```
p3 = Point3 (Point 2 1 2) 3

p3 ^. x -- 1
p3 ^. y -- 2
p3 ^. z -- 3
```

Which is brilliant. However, is there a way to regroup the `makeClassy` and `instance HasPoint2` in one step?